# no matching function for call to ' '

Tags: c++

I was given to implement the function:

```
 "static double distanta (const Complex&, const Complex&);"
```

which return the distance between two Complex numbers. The definition of the function it is inside the Complex class and I have implemented it like that:

```
double Complex::distanta(const Complex &a, const Complex &b)
{    
    double x = a.real() - b.real();
    double y = a.imag() - b.imag();

    return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

As far as I know a static function can only access static members and my class only has

```
double _re;
double _im;
```

as data members.

Within the main function I have called it as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "complex.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Complex* firstComplexNumber; 
    firstComplexNumber = new Complex(81, 93);

    cout << "Numarul complex este: " << *firstComplexNumber << endl;

    Complex* secondComplexNumber;
    secondComplexNumber = new Complex(31, 19);

    cout << "Distanta dintre cele doua numere" <<endl << endl;
    Complex::distanta(firstComplexNumber, secondComplexNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

and the error I get is:

error: no matching function for call to 'Complex::distanta(Complex*&, Complex*&)'

Could you please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is `Complex::distanta` a static method?

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: You are passing two object instances to the static method, so it should have no problem acting on those instances members, if they are exposed.

Comment: As long as it was defined as static double distanta (const Complex&, const Complex&); it seems to me it is a static one.

Comment: A static method simply does not have access to `this`, but it should not be a problem in this case. All of `a.real()`, `b.imag()` etc don't need a `this`.

Comment: What is the line of code corresponding to the error: `no matching function for call to ' '`

Comment: Is that the exact error message, or does it say what the call is? Have you included the class definition before your main function? Without a complete code example, we can only guess what might be wrong.

Comment: Do you have any macro definitions that can collide with you method names?

Comment: I have edited the message. Check it out now.

Comment: @Teodora Why did you not post the full error message before?

Comment: @marcin_j No, I don't.

Comment: You are passing a reference to a pointer

Comment: Why don't you use std::complex<double>?

Comment: It's a homework I'm not supposed to ..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are passing pointers (`Complex*`) when your function takes references (`const Complex&`). A reference and a pointer are entirely different things. When a function expects a reference argument, you need to pass it the object directly. The reference only means that the object is not copied.

To get an object to pass to your function, you would need to dereference your pointers:

```
Complex::distanta(*firstComplexNumber, *secondComplexNumber);
```

Or get your function to take pointer arguments.

However, I wouldn't really suggest either of the above solutions. Since you don't need dynamic allocation here (and you are leaking memory because you don't `delete` what you have `new`ed), you're better off not using pointers in the first place:

```
Complex firstComplexNumber(81, 93);
Complex secondComplexNumber(31, 19);
Complex::distanta(firstComplexNumber, secondComplexNumber);
```

Comment: @Teodora let me guess, Java or C# experience?  `new` is only needed for dynamic lifetime data in C++, and should be used with caution.  Oh, and if sfrabbit's answer solved your problem, give a checkmark to the answer.

Comment: @Teodora It works now, but do you understand why? Also, don't forget to delete your objects off of the heap when you are finished with them.

Comment: No, I have no experience at all, it's my 2nd day writing c++ ..I'm in my first year at uni and have not taken computer science up til now.

Comment: More or less I guess, yeah.

Comment: @Teodora Then, you should re-read sftrabbit's response more carefully, and research referncing, dereferencing, and pointers. You also need to  delete your objects off of the heap after you are done with them. If this were contained in a loop, you'd be creating a bad memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will read about that more carefully. The thing is, I know that I have to delete the objects but I'm not exactly done withe my main function.. I have to test the other 15 functions that I've written which is the reason why I have forgotten to use delete.

Comment: @Teodora Don't dynamically allocate your objects if you don't need to. Prefer the final solution I gave. You won't need to `delete` anything in that case. It's much safer.

Comment: @Teodora Sorry - to be clear, dynamic allocation means using `new` to create an object. While you always have to do that in Java, you almost always want to avoid doing that in C++. C++ has different forms of allocation for different tasks. Here you want what are called *automatic* variables - they automatically destroy the object at the end of the function.

Comment: I see. One more thing though. How come the static function works as long as it should only be able to access static members of the class and I have none?

Comment: @Teodora A static member function can only access static members of its class, not non-static members, because non-static members only exist when you create an object of that type but a static member function is not associated with any particular object. That doesn't mean it has to do that. And it doesn't mean your class has to have static data members to have a static member function. In this case, your function doesn't need to use any static data - its output is entirely dependent on its arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to pass pointers (which you **do not delete**, thus leaking memory) where references are needed. You do not really need pointers here:

```
Complex firstComplexNumber(81, 93);
Complex secondComplexNumber(31, 19);

cout << "Numarul complex este: " << firstComplexNumber << endl;
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ No need to dereference now

// ...

Complex::distanta(firstComplexNumber, secondComplexNumber);
```

Comment: This^ There is no reason to create firstComplexNumber and secondComplexNumber on the heap. If you do create them on the heap, you better remember to delete them when you are done.

Comment: @crush: I think I did point that out. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's why I started by saying `This^`. My comment is an annotation, not a critique.