# error: no matching function for call to ‘ompl::tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors(ompl::geometric::RRT*)’

Tags: c++, motion-planning

when compiling my own project, I got an error as follows:

```
myRRT.cc:80:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘ompl::tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors(ompl::geometric::RRT*)’
        nn_.reset(tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors<Motion *>(this));
                                                                              ^
In file included from /home/htf/Downloads/Active-ORB-SLAM2-octomap/src/myRRT.cc:36:0:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ompl/tools/config/SelfConfig.h:93:42: note: candidate: template<class _T> static ompl::NearestNeighbors<_T>* ompl::tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors(const StateSpacePtr&)
             static NearestNeighbors<_T>* getDefaultNearestNeighbors(const base::StateSpacePtr &space)
                                          ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ompl/tools/config/SelfConfig.h:93:42: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/htf/Downloads/Active-ORB-SLAM2-octomap/src/myRRT.cc:80:78: note:   cannot convert ‘(ompl::geometric::RRT*)this’ (type ‘ompl::geometric::RRT*’) to type ‘const StateSpacePtr& {aka const boost::shared_ptr<ompl::base::StateSpace>&}’
        nn_.reset(tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors<Motion *>(this))
```

here is a part of my source code,

```
void ompl::geometric::RRT::setup()
{
    Planner::setup();
    tools::SelfConfig sc(si_, getName());
    sc.configurePlannerRange(maxDistance_);

    if (!nn_)
       nn_.reset(tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors<Motion *>(this));
    nn_->setDistanceFunction(std::bind(&RRT::distanceFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

this is one of a example file what I have refered[RRT](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/RRTConnect_8cpp_source.html)
does anyone have encountered the similar question?  i'am new to C++, hope to get some clues. thank you in advance.

Comment: Although I am not familiar with motion planning, you can have a look at this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113856/no-matching-function-for-call-to. From your source code and the error it most probably looks like that you need to pass something else rather than "<Motion *>" where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`ompl::tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors(ompl::geometric::RRT*)`
so you should modify it like this:

`nn_.reset(tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors<Motion>(*this));`
maybe `motion` is the templete and (*this) means you want to call object using (*this) 
I am also the green hand. I am not sure.